# Bash - getting return code, stdout and stderr form piped invocations

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stderr

I made a simple logger which has method `logMETHOD`. It's job is to

1. Put `stderr` and `stdout` to a variable `log` (and later to my global `_LOG` variable)
2. Print `stderr` of invoked method on `stderr` and `stdout` on `stdout` so I can see it in a console.
3. Return the return code of a invoked function.

It's invocation looks like this:

```
logMETHOD myMethod arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I figured out how to put standard and error output to both `log` variable and a console but I cannot get the right return code.

My code so far:

```
function logMETHOD {
    exec 5>&1
    local log
    log="$($1 ${@:2} 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/5)"
    local retVal=$?
    _LOG+=$log$'\n'
    return $retVal
}
```

Unfortunately the return code I get comes from (probably) assigning a value (or from `tee` maybe).

BONUS QUESTION:
Is there a possibility to achieve my goals without `2>&1` which connects `stdout` with `stderr` also for console?

I tested solution with 'PIPESTATUS' but the code is still 0.

```
function main {
    logMETHOD alwaysError
}

function logMETHOD {
    exec 5>&1
    local log
    local retVal
    log="$( "$@" 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/5 )"
    retVal=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
    echo "RETVAL: $retVal"
    echo "LOG: $log"
    _LOG+=$log$'\n'
    return $retVal
}

function alwaysError {
    return 1
}

main $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PIPESTATUS` would be a good solution, but here it already holds the return value of the `log=...` assignment. If you want the return value of the `"$@"...` you have to write it like this:

```
log="$( "$@" 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/5; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}>/tmp/retval )"
retVal=$(</tmp/retval)
```

Assigning it to a variable would not work, because its scope would not extend to the calling shell, so you have to resort to using a tempfile.

As for `stderr`, `$()` can only extract `stdout`, therefore you have to use a tempfile for that too, if you want to handle it separately.

```
log="$( "$@" 2>/tmp/stderr | tee /dev/fd/5; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}>/tmp/retval )"
stderr_log=$(</tmp/stderr)
retVal=$(</tmp/retval)
```

If you just want to spare the redirection:

```
log="$( "$@" |& tee /dev/fd/5; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}>/tmp/retval )"
```

From `man bash`:

> If |& is used, command's  standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2's standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for 2>&1 |.  This implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by the command.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to use `PIPESTATUS` to retrieve the exit status of the command.

```
# There's no need to split $1 off of $@ to run the command.
log=$( "$@" 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/5 )
local retVal=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Comment: RETVAL is still 0 for invocation of "logMETHOD ls /bullshitdirectory"